# I want preview image before selecting image

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, preview

Visual Studio 2017, winforms
I want preview image before selecting image
When I select an image for the Image control in the image listing screen it's not in preview mode

==> So how do I make it show the preview.
[Picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqlO4.png)
Thank you.

Comment: This sound like a windows issue, just right click on the folder where your images are and set the view to large icons

Comment: I think it should be window problem, usually cased by memory error (e.g: out of memory in ram or local drive). However I suggest an alternative solution: you can format your files name and recognize your file by their name